# classify all the conjugate classes in $GL_3 (\mathbb{F}_q)$ , whose characteristic polynomial is $x^3$ in terms of Jordan canonical forms

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $ \vert \mathbb{F}_q  \vert = q$.

The problem is that : Classify all the conjugate classes in $GL_3 (\mathbb{F}_q)$ , whose characteristic polynomial is $x^3$ in terms of Jordan canonical forms.

Let me introduce my approach :
Let A be a matrix  in $GL_3 (\mathbb{F}_q)$ .  As i know, all the eigenvalue of A are $0$ because the minimal polynomial for A divides the chacteristic polynomial $x^3$ of A  . So detA is $0$ which is contradiction for $A \in GL_3 (\mathbb{F}_q)$ Can you point out me my fault? thank you for your help!

Comment: You have done nothing wrong.  It seems likely that the problem was intended to be something else.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. this problem is part (a) and next part question is "(b) compute the size of each conjugacy class in the above question".